# Unity android leaderboard login

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am very first time implementing the google leaderboard in one of the android games developed on Unity platform. I think i did everything right (according to some tutorial i was following) but when i try to login into the google game play services i get the following exception "  Using Google Play games services requires a     metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest. 
Missing metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest." 
While the metadata tag is there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application>

 <!-- Required for Nearby Connections API -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.SERVICE_ID"
        android:value="" />

    <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="\ 686*********" />

    <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
        android:value="\ 0.9.41" />

    <!-- Build time check to make sure play-services libraries are present -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Can you delete the \ character front of your value(686..) and try again ?

Comment: Thats the way to declare it as string instead of integer value, but still i tried for  you and did not work :)

Comment: thanks :) can you share your manifest file ?

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Can you also add this `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="\ 686*********" />`

Comment: I added but no luck :( very strange issue

Comment: I also tried to change the package name of the manifest for just a hit but did not work as well.

Comment: Yes, it is weird. I researched but don't find the solution. I think, you should sure plugins are updated and you can try rebuild.

Comment: "GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.41.unitypackage" is the name of plugin i am using, which i think is the latest one by google itself. I even created a new unity app, imported this plugin and implemented basic instantiation and login code but still same exception.

Comment: Some of users say the version has mistakes. Can you try downgrade to 0.9.38 ?

Comment: AT LAST i got it working with version 0.9.38, what a shitty update by google is 0.9.41 . Thank you very much mate you were really very helpful.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after struggling for two days, it was a bug of GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.41.unitypackage while after downgrading to version 0.9.38a it worked as expected.